# how do I fix "The specified domain either does not exist..." when issuing net user /domain command?

Tags: windows-7

cmd.exe, Administrator level:

```
C:\Windows\system32>net user jcollum /domain
The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain XXXX.YYYYY.

System error 1355 has occurred.

The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
```

The username is correct, as far as I can tell. We've recently swapped domain controller servers. I'm having trouble copying a large set of files from a server to a portable drive (running into permission errors).

Comment: `1.` What are you trying to accomplish? Your command will list the user account details, nothing more. Are you trying to verify that the account exists in the domain? `2.` Have you verified that the client machine you're running the command on has the correct DNS servers configured?

Comment: `1`: yes, I just want to see my user details; I'm trying to change ownership on a folder and running into issues with it, so I did `net user` and saw this error. I think the error is related to the issues I'm running into. `2`: I have no idea how to do that.